# Why do I get a blank page on my shop after paying with Paypal?

Tags: paypal, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

When I make the payment with PayPal on my website prestashop, after Checkout Payment, the page turns white and stop working instead of come back to validate page of PayPal where we can find the opportunity to return to the store with the number of transaction and a confirmation message like "Payment Completed"

so I decided to reload the white page, and it came back to my website and it told me :

```
"Error occured : Merci de vous reférer aux logs :
1.  PayPal response:
    2.  CHECKOUTSTATUS -> PaymentActionCompleted
3.  TIMESTAMP -> 2012-12-08T22:35:15Z
4.  EMAIL -> thomaslacroix149@me.com
5.  PAYERID -> 6E5PYX5CHP6N6
6.  PAYERSTATUS -> verified
7.  FIRSTNAME -> Thomas
8.  LASTNAME -> Lacroix
9.  COUNTRYCODE -> FR
10. SHIPTONAME -> Thomas Lacroix
11. SHIPTOSTREET -> 5 Rue St Hermentaire
12. SHIPTOCITY -> Martigues
13. SHIPTOZIP -> 13500
14. SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE -> FR
15. SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME -> France
16. ADDRESSSTATUS -> Unconfirmed
17. CURRENCYCODE -> EUR
18. AMT -> 1.01
19. ITEMAMT -> 0.01
20. SHIPPINGAMT -> 1.00
21. HANDLINGAMT -> 0.00
22.     TAXAMT -> 0.00
23.     INSURANCEAMT -> 0.00
24.     SHIPDISCAMT -> 0.00
25. L_NAME0 -> Divers
26. L_NUMBER0 -> 201
27. L_QTY0 -> 1
28. L_TAXAMT0 -> 0.00
29. L_AMT0 -> 0.01
30. L_DESC0 -> ...
31. L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
32. L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
33. L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
34. L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
35. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE -> EUR
36. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT -> 1.01
37. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT -> 0.01
38. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT -> 1.00
39. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT -> 0.00
40. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT -> 0.00
41. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT -> 0.00
42. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT -> 0.00
43. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID -> 2B4648015B651205G
44. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED -> false
45. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME -> Thomas Lacroix
46. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET -> 5 Rue St Hermentaire
47. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY -> Martigues
48. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP -> 13500
49. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE -> FR
50. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME -> France
51. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS -> Unconfirmed
52. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 -> Divers
53. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 -> 201
54. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 -> 1
55. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0 -> 0.00
56. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 -> 0.01
57. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0 -> ...
58. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
59. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
60. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
61. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
62. PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID -> 2B4648015B651205G
63. PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE -> 0
64. Cart changed since the last checkout express, please make a new Paypal checkout payment
```

So I couldn't complete the payment method.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? I'd like to know, because I have the exact same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two known issues related to this.

- You need to add 755 rights on `modules/paypal` directory.
- Maybe the `tools/tcpdf/tcpdf.php` file is corrupted and you need to get a new version of it (you can get it by downloading a fresh install of Prestashop).